# Which USB touchpads works well in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: touchpad

I would like to replace my mouse with an external USB touchpad. Which USB touchpad will give me the least amount of driver headache in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether there is a driver - either opensource or by the manufacturer (or both) - for your touchpad. Check the manufacturers support site for linux drivers or google for your preferred touchpad together with "ubuntu driver".

Touchpads by Synaptics will work definitely. You need to get the driver via apt:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```